# TS compiler throwing errors for transfer_state.d.ts file in node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\ directory

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, npm, angular-cli

My TS compiler is throwing about 7 errors for transfer_state.d.ts file in node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\src\browser\ directory

The offending line is as follows:

```
export declare function makeStateKey<T = void>(key: string): StateKey<T>;
```

the entire file looks like this:

````
export declare function escapeHtml(text: string): string;
export declare function unescapeHtml(text: string): string;
/**
 * A type-safe key to use with `TransferState`.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * ```
 * const COUNTER_KEY = makeStateKey<number>('counter');
 * let value = 10;
 *
 * transferState.set(COUNTER_KEY, value);
 * ```
 *
 * @experimental
 */
export declare type StateKey<T> = string & {
    __not_a_string: never;
};
/**
 * Create a `StateKey<T>` that can be used to store value of type T with `TransferState`.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * ```
 * const COUNTER_KEY = makeStateKey<number>('counter');
 * let value = 10;
 *
 * transferState.set(COUNTER_KEY, value);
 * ```
 *
 * @experimental
 */
export declare function makeStateKey<T = void>(key: string): StateKey<T>;
/**
 * A key value store that is transferred from the application on the server side to the application
 * on the client side.
 *
 * `TransferState` will be available as an injectable token. To use it import
 * `ServerTransferStateModule` on the server and `BrowserTransferStateModule` on the client.
 *
 * The values in the store are serialized/deserialized using JSON.stringify/JSON.parse. So only
 * boolean, number, string, null and non-class objects will be serialized and deserialzied in a
 * non-lossy manner.
 *
 * @experimental
 */
export declare class TransferState {
    private store;
    private onSerializeCallbacks;
    /**
     * Get the value corresponding to a key. Return `defaultValue` if key is not found.
     */
    get<T>(key: StateKey<T>, defaultValue: T): T;
    /**
     * Set the value corresponding to a key.
     */
    set<T>(key: StateKey<T>, value: T): void;
    /**
     * Remove a key from the store.
     */
    remove<T>(key: StateKey<T>): void;
    /**
     * Test whether a key exists in the store.
     */
    hasKey<T>(key: StateKey<T>): boolean;
    /**
     * Register a callback to provide the value for a key when `toJson` is called.
     */
    onSerialize<T>(key: StateKey<T>, callback: () => T): void;
    /**
     * Serialize the current state of the store to JSON.
     */
    toJson(): string;
}
export declare function initTransferState(doc: Document, appId: string): TransferState;
/**
 * NgModule to install on the client side while using the `TransferState` to transfer state from
 * server to client.
 *
 * @experimental
 */
export declare class BrowserTransferStateModule {
}
````

I have tried many different TS compilers and played with the tsconfig.json quite a bit. I have reinstalled node to make sure that this file is not somehow corrupt.

This is only a problem when trying to compile in Visual studio 2015, and not when I use ng server.

I need this to work in VS2015. but not sure whats going on.

My versions are:

typescript 2.3.4 (tried 2.7.2 and 2.6.2 and others)
NPM version is 5.6.0
my angular version is 5.2.5
my angular CLI is 1.7.1
Node is 6.10.2
Webpack is 3.11.0

Answer (score 0):

Updating my visual studio compiler fixed this (my npm compiler was already up-to-date)

When compiling in Visual studio, the visual studio typescript compiler is used, even if there is a tsconfig.json and a package.json file in the app. To allow the angular app to run through either node or visual studio, then you need to have a compatible typescript compiler for both visual studio and node.